# Openpose error "zsh: abort ./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --image_dir examples/media/"

Tags: macos, openpose

I have downloaded openpose on mac and I tried the command

`./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --image_dir examples/media/`

however, I am getting this a warning and it stops the execution.

```
Starting OpenPose demo...
Configuring OpenPose...
Starting thread(s)...
---------------------------------- WARNING ----------------------------------
We have introduced an additional boost in accuracy in the CUDA version of about 0.2% with respect to the CPU/OpenCL versions. We will not port this to CPU given the considerable slow down in speed it would add to it. Nevertheless, this accuracy boost is almost insignificant so the CPU/OpenCL versions can be safely used.
-------------------------------- END WARNING --------------------------------
src/tcmalloc] Attempt to free invalid pointer 
zsh: abort      ./build/examples/openpose/openpose.bin --image_dir examples/media/
```